# Rush Hour table for every day in a month MySQL

Tags: mysql, reporting

I'm trying to make a query to get rush hours for everyday on a specific month. 
The table I have looks like this:

```
id      idproduct       created_at
1       021354684       2011-10-01 20:25:48
2       033546835       2011-10-01 20:30:15
3       055965654       2011-10-01 20:45:20
4       012975343       2011-10-02 14:03:36
5       021354684       2011-10-02 15:55:48
6       033546835       2011-10-02 16:30:15
7       055965654       2011-10-02 16:45:20
8       012975343       2011-10-02 18:53:36
9       021354684       2011-10-03 08:55:48
10      033546835       2011-10-03 09:30:15
11      055965654       2011-10-03 14:03:20
12      012975343       2011-10-03 14:03:36
```

What I try to get is  something like this...:

```
day     rush_hour    number_of_rows
1       20:00        3
2       16:00        5
3       14:00        4
```

Is it possible to get a table like this? can you guys help me?

I made a mistake, sorry for this. The number of rows should be the total of items sold that day, not in that hour :( sorry.

Comment: so, you'll want to group the created_at by day and rush hours? Is there a timeframe, like 1am to 2am, 2am to 3am, ...?

Comment: There isn't but would be useful to have one like 1am to 2am hehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b87b/7

First, count every day's every hour's count (into a view, because we will use it twice below):

```
CREATE VIEW hours AS 
SELECT
  DATE( created_at ) AS d,
  HOUR( created_at ) AS h,
  COUNT(*) AS c
FROM item
GROUP BY DATE(created_at), HOUR(created_at);
```

Final query:

```
SELECT
  hours.d AS `day`,
  hours.h AS `rush_hour`,
  hours.c AS `count`

-- get the max count for every day
FROM (
      SELECT
        d,          -- the day 
        MAX(c) as c -- the count
      FROM hours
      GROUP BY d
     ) AS maxc

-- find the actual hour(s) with the max count for every day:
INNER JOIN hours ON hours.c = maxc.c
                AND hours.d = maxc.d;
```

Comment: Of course you can copy-paste the view's select into the second query, if you want.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works prefect! The only thing is that i get the 355 days of the year hehe. But it works :)

Comment: Sorry my mistake, the solution was ok but i had to edit what i asked. I will give put it back as "ok". The result i asked first wasnt right (your solution was but not my question) I edited the number of rows to get the total of items sold that day and just one rush hour.

Comment: Hi, I updated the sqlfiddle to also contain daily counts: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b87b/34

Comment: Omg ty Biziclop! You're a demon! :D

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to look at the [MySQL Date Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html), they offer you some help with this

```
SELECT 
  day(created_at) as day, 
  hour(created_at) as rush_hour, 
  count(1) as num_rows 
FROM item
GROUP BY
  day(created_at), hour(created_at)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62a15/2/0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT dayofyear(created_at) as day, hour(created_at) as rush_hour, count(*) as number_of_rows 
FROM table
GROUP BY dayofyear(created_at), hour(created_at);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is without making a view:

```
SELECT ddd.day, eee.rush_hour, ddd.maxo
FROM 
(select day, max(num_rows) as maxo from (
SELECT 
  day(created_at) as day, 
  hour(created_at) as rush_hour, 
  count(1) as num_rows 
FROM item
GROUP BY
  day(created_at), hour(created_at)
  ) as groupo group by day) as ddd

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
  day(created_at) as day, 
  hour(created_at) as rush_hour, 
  count(1) as num_rows 
FROM item
GROUP BY
  day(created_at), hour(created_at)
  ) as eee on ddd.day=eee.day and ddd.maxo=eee.num_rows
```

I could imagine it being formatted more nicely or having more relevant aliases, but there's just so much subselecting going on here.

And thanks SQLfiddlers for putting the data there.

And I think that if you have two hours tied for the highest number of whatever it is you are counting, they both will show up, so you'll get two (or more) records returned for that day of the month.

Comment: This one works pretty good but i have no idea what month is doing it. Im getting 31 days and the results. Ty for your help!